# Error when using AMPscript to show fallback value if First Name isn't present

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using this AMPscript to show someone's first name if it's present in the Data Extension, and if it isn't, it should just show "Hello".

```
%%[ 
VAR @firstName
SET @firstName = AttributeValue("First Name")
]%%
%%=iif(empty(@firstName),'Hello',concat("Dear ",@firstName))=%%,
```

I'm getting this error when no first name is present.  It works when a first name is present:

**"invalid index (parameter 2) passed to Row function. Index must be less than or equal to the row count. Index Value: 1 Row Count: 0 Function: row(@rows,1)"**

What is missing from the AMPscript please?

Comment: Judging from the error, I think this is an issue stemming from syntax issues outside the provided snippet. Can you provide further context? It mentions a Row() function, if you could make sure to include that as well, it would greatly help.

Comment: Is this the entirety of your AMPscript code? Are you getting this error when attempting to preview the message, or are you validating through another method?

Comment: I worked it out, the AMPscript in the Plain Text version hadn't updated from the email I copied it from.